# Using css module in react app. How can I get rid of styles keyword

Tags: css, reactjs

I used css modules in my react app and here is my code:

```
import styles from './PlayerCard.module.css';
import PlayerPhoto from '../../images/players/Farahani.png';

export default function PlayerCard() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.PlayerCard}>
      <img className={styles.PlayerPhoto} src={PlayerPhoto} alt="Player" />
      <p className={styles.PlayerName}>Farahani</p>

      <div className={styles.SkillBox}>
        <div className={styles.SkillName}>
          <p>Defence:</p>
```

How can I get rid of those styles keywords? is there any way like destructuring or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring).

```js
import styles from './PlayerCard.module.css';
import PlayerPhoto from '../../images/players/Farahani.png';

const { PlayerCard: PlayerCardStyle, PlayerPhoto: PlayerPhotoStyle, PlayerName: PlayerNameStyle, SkillBox, SkillName } = styles;

export default function PlayerCard() {
  return (
    <div className={PlayerCardStyle}>
      <img className={PlayerPhotoStyle} src={PlayerPhoto} alt="Player" />
      <p className={PlayerNameStyle}>Farahani</p>

      <div className={styles.SkillBox}>
        <div className={styles.SkillName}>
          <p>Defence:</p>
```

Note that for `PlayerCard`, `PlayerPhoto`, and `PlayerName`, I need to [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_to_new_variable_names) it to different names so that they don't get conflicted with the components' names.

Alternatively, you can also import the styles like below:

```js
import { PlayerCard as PlayerCardStyle, PlayerPhoto as PlayerPhotoStyle, PlayerName as PlayerNameStyle, SkillBox, SkillName } from './PlayerCard.module.css'
```

Similarly, you also have to [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#syntax) the imports.